# Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble getting 'Year' to be a default value of the current Year if there is no value.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
Year = int.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Year").AttemptedValue ?? now.Year);
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that

```
bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Year").AttemptedValue
```

is of `string` type,`??` operator expect both left/right values are of the same type.

As a case you can do *now.Year.ToString()*:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
Year = int.Parse(
             bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Year").AttemptedValue 
             ?? now.Year.ToString());
```

Comment: May I suggest using `code blocks` instead of *italics* for code? (also, operator is misspelled)

Comment: Thanks for notes, will update my answer. Just recall why I was using italic :) I was editing Confluence page and used italic there :)

Comment: Even you decided to accept my answer I would suggest using `TryParse()` as specified in answer of `viggity`

Answer (score 7):

You have to apply the coalesce operator on two like types. String and int are not the same. Try this instead:

```
var year = 0;
if(!int.TryParse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Year").AttemptedValue, out year))
    year = DateTime.Now.Year;
```

In the example, year will only be replaced if the AttemptedValue is parsable into an integer, otherwise it'll be the current year.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.ToString()`:

```
Year = int.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Year").AttemptedValue ?? now.Year.ToString());
```

Both variables need to be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one of your values is a string and one is an int therefore it cannot decide what to convert too

You need to make sure that the types match and this problem should go away.

I would use .ToString() so that they are both strings.